# Free replacement for Picasa Desktop (photo manager, no cloud)

Tags: gratis, photography, image-editing

Google [announced](http://googlephotos.blogspot.hr/2016/02/moving-on-from-picasa.html) they're killing Picasa Desktop (and Picasa web). The software they propose in place of the Desktop version only allows you to upload to Google Photos (backup). There were other Picasa Desktop features that are/were useful:

- photo editing
- photo organizing (albums, tags, face recognition, etc.)
- intelligent syncing photos from external cameras
- etc.

I know Picasa will continue to work for some time (there has been little support over the years). But a follow-up product is certainly needed.

What **free** products exist that fill this gap?

I don't want to have to upload my gazillion photos to the cloud, for several reasons: privacy, bandwidth, image compression (lossy), and having to pay eventually for extra storage. I'm on Windows or Linux and use a hard drive for backups. I'm not a professional photographer, but take photos at work and with family.

Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/228260/good-process-software-for-organizing-photos-past-present

Comment: There is what appears to be a remarkably comprehensive comparison of image viewers available on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_image_viewers

Comment: Just read this: 9 open source alternatives to Picasa

http://flip.it/MBCDm

Comment: Fuhrminator, the photo managers in the above article appear to be for Linux only (1 KDE and 3 GNOME). It's my understanding that Picasa runs on Windows and Mac, but not Linux. Am I behind the times and missing something?

Comment: @markproxy the article sez: "Picasa was available across multiple platforms, and while it had not been recently packaged for Linux, it still worked well for many Linux users inside of Wine."

Comment: Thx -- I missed that!

Answer (score 4):

**[Xn View](http://www.xnview.com/en/)**

XnView is organized as freeware for private non-commercial or educational use is really a utility for viewing and converting graphic files.

It supports Image IPTC, EXIF metadata, EXIF auto rotation, IPTC edition, Batch convert, batch rename, Create or edit Multi-page file (TIFF,DCX, LDF), 44 languages (Windows only), Multipage TIFF, Animated GIF, Animated ICO.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Could you please [edit] your answer and include how *Xn View* fits the other requirements (photo editing (not just the metadata), syncing)? Also: is just the support of 44 languages restricted to Windows – or is the entire application available for Windows only?

Comment: XnView is cool but has no single feature about tags or metadata database, so doesn't fit the question.