# Image beautifying software

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for a program that will automatically beautify images, similar to Picasa Desktop's "I'm Feeling Lucky" editing option.

A plug-in for image software would do the trick as well.

This question was raised in [Free replacement for Picasa Desktop (photo manager, no cloud)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28766/free-replacement-for-picasa-desktop-photo-manager-no-cloud) but not answered.

Comment: The problem is that there is not a universal standard for  beauty https://petapixel.com/2015/08/15/one-woman-photoshopped-by-18-countries-beauty-standards-revealed/ is one great example.

Comment: Define "beautify", so that people who haven't used Picasa themselves can answer the question.